# CRYSTAL REPORT - SHOW FIELD IN GROUP HEADER BASED ON THE DATA IN GROUP DETAILS

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have a problem that needs to resolve.

*I have group header and group details.
*I wanted to put a field in group header inside a textbox based on the data that has on the group details.

see picture for more details:
[group header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqhwj.png)
[group details image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qNEm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a detail formula:
IF {Loan.Type} = "CAL" or {Loan.Type} = "MPL" Then 1 ELSE 0

Then, in the group header use a **SUM** of that formula for the group to find out if there are such cases.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But my problem is that to display a field name start_term to group header. My report is group by eyername field, every eyername have many midno filed as you can see in group details image. In some scenario, some MPL alone in specific eyername, and CAL alone in some eyername. But there is sometime both CAL AND MPL in specific eyername

Comment: If MPL only: MPL - 'START_TERM'  CAL - 'NONE'.     If CAL only: MPL - 'NONE'  CAL - START_TERM              and lastly if both exist then put start_term both